# Symfony 3.4 Insert data using RESTful API without bundle

Tags: php, ajax, rest, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have a problem inserting data to database.

I can insert using this code:

```
$quote->setSource($data['quote_form[source]']);
$quote->setQuote($data['quote_form[quote]']);
```

what i want is insert data without adding specific fields.

Problems:

1. The problem in my first code is if I'm going to add a new field i need to add over and over again a new set.
2. When i add `if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())` it doesn't enter in the if condition.

This is the code of my function in controller :

```
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
            $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
            $quote = new Quote();
            $form = $this->createForm(QuoteForm::class, $quote)->submit($data);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                // Add our quote to Doctrine so that it can be saved
                $em->persist($quote);

                // Save our quote
                $em->flush();
            } else {
                echo 'not valid';die();
            }

            return new Response('It\'s probably been saved', 201);
        } else {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException();
        }
    }
```

For the Html Ajax:

```
function serializeFormJSON(formArray) {
    var returnArray = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < formArray.length; i++) {
        returnArray[formArray[i]['name']] = formArray[i]['value'];
    }

    return returnArray;
}

var form = $('form[name=quote_form]');
    form.submit(function (e) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(serializeFormJSON($(this).serializeArray())));
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(serializeFormJSON($(this).serializeArray())),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
        });
    });
```

I just get also the idea here

-> https://andrewadcock.com/a-simple-restful-api-tutorial-with-symfony-3/

-> https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-rest/form-post

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your form is not valid. There is method in form object

```
$form->getErrors();
```

It returns collection of validation errors. There is also section in symfony profiler related to form validation errors:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi9dM.png)

Comment: thanks for this i found my problem in validation. i just disable the csrf_token